# Java LIBGDX, Calling InputHandler's TouchDown method from another class

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I just started with LibGDX and Java, and I need a little help. I am having problem with calling a touchdown method from inputhandlers class.

This is a InputHandler class:

```
public class InputHandler implements InputProcessor {
private Bird myBird;
private GameWorld myWorld;

public InputHandler(GameWorld myWorld) {

   this.myWorld = myWorld;
   myBird = myWorld.getBird();
}

@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

    if (myWorld.isReady()) {
        myWorld.start();
    }

    myBird.onClick();

    if (myWorld.isGameOver() || myWorld.isHighScore()) {
        // Reset all variables, go to GameState.READ
        myWorld.restart();
    } 
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
    return false;
}

}
```

I would like that my GameScreen class calls a TouchDown method because I created a stage and a actor(button) with a scene2d. I hope that you understand my problem and thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have not set the instance of this class as `InputProcessor`.

Try

```
InputHandler handler = new InputHandler(world);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(handler);
```

---

If you want to set multiple `InputProcessor`s, you can use a `InputMultiplexer`.

Here is the [api link](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputMultiplexer.html).

---

The [wiki for this topic](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/handlingUserInput) also seems very useful.

Hope this helps.
Good Luck.